# How to run futures containing borrowed TcpStream concurrently?

Tags: rust, async-await, future, asyncsocket

I am trying to make this code snippet run concurrently instead of sequentially since the number of peers can be a large value. I am using `async_std 1.4` and rust `1.41`

```rust
pub struct Peer {
    pub peer_id: String,
    pub tcp_stream: Arc<TcpStream>,
    pub public_key: [u8; 32],
}

async fn send_to_all_peers(message: Protocol, peers: &HashMap<String,Peer>) -> Result<()> {
    for peer in peers.values() {
        let mut stream = &*peer.tcp_stream;
        stream.write_all(&bincode::serialize(&message)?).await?;
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

I've tried to use the `futures::future::join_all` method without any luck since wrapping future I created and used within `async_std::task::spawn` requires a static lifetime. Here is what I tried:

```rust
async fn send_to_all_peers(message: Protocol, peers: &HashMap<String,Peer>) {
    let handles = peers.values().into_iter().map(|peer| {
        task::spawn(
            async {
                let mut stream = &*peer.tcp_stream;
                if let Err(err) = stream
                    .write_all(&bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap())
                    .await
                {
                    error!("Error when writing to tcp_stream: {}", err);
                }
            }
        )
    });
    futures::future::join_all(handles).await;
}
```

I'm sure there is some method I am missing, thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are trying to send message concurrently, each task has to have its own copy of the message:

```
use async_std::{task, net::TcpStream};
use futures::{future, io::AsyncWriteExt};
use serde::Serialize;
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    error::Error,
    sync::Arc,
};

pub struct Peer {
    pub peer_id: String,
    pub tcp_stream: Arc<TcpStream>,
    pub public_key: [u8; 32],
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct Protocol;

async fn send_to_all_peers(
    message: Protocol,
    peers: &HashMap<String, Peer>)
    -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
{
    let msg = bincode::serialize(&message)?;
    let handles = peers.values()
        .map(|peer| {
            let msg = msg.clone();
            let socket = peer.tcp_stream.clone();
            task::spawn(async move {
                let mut socket = &*socket;
                socket.write_all(&msg).await
            })
        });

    future::try_join_all(handles).await?;
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Thank you! this solved it. I was hoping I could get around cloning the `Arc<TcpStream>` but I guess it's impossible to do safely.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
let handles = peers.values().into_iter().map(|peer| {
   let mut stream = &*peer.tcp_stream;
   stream.write_all(&bincode::serialize(&message).unwrap())
}
let results = futures::future::join_all(handles).await
```

?

Notice how the .map closure doesn’t await, but straight up returns a future, which is then passed to join_all, and then awaited.

Comment: I've tried that with another issue of lifetimes, this is the basic jist of the error:
```rust    stream.write_all(message) returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

```